# seeking explanation on the jgroups multicast IP address

Tags: jgroups

Can you guys help me understand this mcast_addr="224.0.0.35" in jgroups   configuration
Is it correct that its a "virtual" ip on the network and not a physical ip address
so jgroups is using this IP to multicast information between different nodes.
I am looking for the rules to configure this address, what is the range? why is it needed etc.

```
<UDP ip_mcast="false" mcast_addr="224.0.0.35" mcast_port="45566" ip_ttl="32"
            mcast_send_buf_size="150000" mcast_recv_buf_size="80000"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a multicast (class D) address. Any packet sent to this address (and port) is forwarded (by the switch) to all processes which have subscribed (joined) to the same address:port.
If you google for 'IP multicast address', you'll find recommended ranges to be used.